# Why is prototypical inherited child class an instance of another child class?

Tags: javascript

Perhaps I'm doing this wrong. I want to set up a base class and two classes that inherit from that class. However, it is telling me that one child is an instanceof the other child... that can't be correct, can it? What am i doing wrong here?

```
function BaseClass(){}
function Child1(){}

Child1.prototype = BaseClass.prototype;
Child1.prototype.constructor = Child1;

function Child2(){}
Child2.prototype = BaseClass.prototype;
Child2.prototype.constructor = Child2;

console.log((new Child1() instanceof Child2)); // true
```

Comment: Here's a good resource on the many ways of using inheritance in JS: http://www.3site.eu/doc/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Child1.prototype = BaseClass.prototype;`

Should be `Child1.prototype = Object.create(BaseClass.prototype)`

You don't want the prototype object to be the same, you want a new prototype object that inherits from `BaseClass`

[Live Example](http://jsfiddle.net/d4gCj/)

**Disclaimer:** `Object.create` is ES5, use the [ES5-shim](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim) for legacy platform support.

To give you a more thorough example :

```
// Create base prototype
var Base = {
  method: function () {
    return this.things;
  },
  constructor: function (things) {
    this.things = things;
  }
};
// Link constructor and prototype
Base.constructor.prototype = Base;

// Create child prototype that inherits from Base
var Child = Object.create(Base);
// overwrite constructor
Child.constructor = function (things) {
  things++;
  Base.constructor.call(things);
}
// Link constructor and prototype
Child.constructor.prototype = Child;

// Swap prototype and constructor around to support new
ChildFactory = Child.constructor;

var c = new ChildFactory(41);
console.log(c.method()); // 42
```

**Visually:**

`var Base = { ... }`

here we simply create an object with methods and properties. We want to be able to create an *instance* of this object. So `Base` is a "class" and all it's methods and properties can be accessed from the instances (including `constructor`).

`Base.constructor.prototype = Base;`

You need to link the "Constructor function" which is a function you can call with `new` which will give you a new instance of the object `ConstructorFunction.prototype` together with the prototype object. This is basically a bit of glue you need to do manually because ES does not do this for you.

If you forgot to do this then the constructor function (which is `X.constructor`) doesn't have a `.prototype` property to make instances inherit from.

`var Child = Object.create(Base);`

Create a new object whose `[[Prototype]]` is `Base`. This basically is the start of your prototype chain

```
Child -> ([[Prototype]] = Base) -> ([[Prototype]] = Object.prototype) -> null
```

`Child.x = ...`

Now we add properties to our child object which are the methods instances of Child will inherit. Basically we are creating a new prototype object to inherit from. All instances will share the methods and also share the methods up the prototype chain (including `Base`).

`ChildFactory = Child.constructor;`

the `new` key word only works on constructor functions and not prototype objects so we need to basically say "switch our prototype object variable to the constructor function variable"

Personally when building up "classes" I find the prototype objects really pleasant to handle directly and when creating instances I find the constructor functions pleasant to handle.

Now when we call `var c = new Child(41);`

It will call the constructor function we defined which will increment `things`, then call the base constructor.

Note at this point the prototype chain of c looks like

```
c -> ([[Prototype]] = Child) 
  -> ([[Prototype]] = Base) 
  -> ([[Prototype]] = Object.prototype) 
  -> null
```

Comment: Thanks! This works like a charm... I'll have to do some more reading on this to see what is going on behind the scenes. There are so many different examples on the net about how to do inheritance properly, and they all seem to have parameterless constructors to avoid the hard bits :)

Answer (score 3):

You've set the prototype of both your classes to exactly the same object ("BaseClass.prototype"), and set the "constructor" property on it to "Child2". In other words "Child1.prototype" and "Child2.prototype" are the same, so there's only one "constructor" property involved in your code, and it ends up being "Child2".

Maybe you want to set those prototypes to *instances* of BaseClass?

```
Child1.prototype = new BaseClass();
Child1.prototype.constructor = Child1;

Child2.prototype = new BaseClass(); // a different object
Child2.prototype.constructor = Child2;
```

(@Raynos points out that instantiating the prototype value like that may cause subtle problems, so you might prefer using the approach in his answer.)

Comment: You really should avoid `.prototype = new X()` you dont want to initialize `.prototype` as an instance of X, you just want to instantiate. (i.e. don't call the constructor!)

Comment: What happens when your base class constructor has arguments -- do you need to initialize them right then and there? My real child class code has a call to BaseClass.call(this, 'argument1', 'argument2'); in its constructor.

Comment: OK @Raynos yes that's probably true; I don't do that sort of thing often enough to have dealt with such issues :-)  I'll add a not.

Comment: @ShyGuy I think that's why many object frameworks use a convention of having an "init" function to call.

Comment: @ShyGuy you don't initialize them then and there, you do it in the constructor of the child.

Comment: @Pointy :( many object frameworks recommend "init" because they are dirty hacks. you just don't use constructors when inheriting (tip: `Object.create` does what you want).

Comment: @Raynos you certainly know more about this than I do :-)  I haven't written "object-y" code in JavaScript in a long time, though I write a lot of JavaScript. (Also, isn't `Object.create` an ES5 thing?  Probably there's a polyfill at MDN.)

Comment: @Pointy Yes it is, I have this bad habit of thinking "ES5" whenever anyone says JavaScript. I just can't turn it off!

Answer (score 1):

If you assign to prototype, doesn't that mean that you overwrite it completely? So that Child1 and Child2 actually become BaseClass objects, rather than child classes.

See also http://www.zipcon.net/~swhite/docs/computers/languages/object_oriented_JS/inheritance.html . Proper OO in JS takes quite some effort.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't mean the check whether the object `new Child1()` is created by the “Child1” constructor. The `instanceof` operator only takes an object prototype — `(new Child1()).[[Prototype]]` and checks its presence in the prototype chain, starring examination from the “Child1.prototype”. Operator `instanceof` is activated via the internal [[HasInstance]] method of the constructor.
So you need to change your code in the following way:

```
function BaseClass(){}
function Child1(){}

Child1.prototype = new BaseClass();
Child1.prototype.constructor = Child1;

function Child2(){}
Child2.prototype = new BaseClass();
Child2.prototype.constructor = Child2;
console.log((new Child1() instanceof Child2)); // false
```

And it will be correct implementation of OOP in javascript